# Unir listas de objetos declaradas en en una variable result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

avor su ayuda para poder unir las listas de objetos declaradas en diferentes variables, con el objetivo de crear una nueva variable que contenga todas estas listas , sin concatenarlas.

Hago esto porque estoy buscando información de una tabla llamadas Producto, pero hay algunas columnas "ID" , que hacen referencia a otras tablas , entonces quiero llamar a esos campos y no mostrar el ID.

este es mi codigo CS

```
public List<PRODUCTO> GetPRODUCTO()
        {
            var tipoApi = db.TIPOPRODUCTO.AsQueryable();
            var unidadApi = db.UNIDADMEDIDA.AsQueryable();
            var proveeApi = db.PROVEEDOR.AsQueryable();
            var productApi = db.PRODUCTO.AsQueryable();
            var productApiFiltered = productApi.ToList();
            var tipoApiFiltered = tipoApi.ToList();
            var unidadApiFiltered = unidadApi.ToList();
            var proveeApiFiltered = proveeApi.ToList();
            PRODUCTO pRODUCTO = new PRODUCTO();
            PROVEEDOR pROVEEDOR = new PROVEEDOR();
            UNIDADMEDIDA uNIDADMEDIDA = new UNIDADMEDIDA();
            TIPOPRODUCTO tIPOPRODUCTO = new TIPOPRODUCTO();
            var list = new List<PRODUCTO>();
            var list1 = new List<PROVEEDOR>();
            var list2 = new List<UNIDADMEDIDA>();
            var list3 = new List<TIPOPRODUCTO>();
            var result = 

            foreach (var item in productApiFiltered)
            {

                if (productApiFiltered != null)
                {
                    var newProduct = new PRODUCTO()
                    {
                        ID = item.ID,
                        NOMBRE = item.NOMBRE,
                        DETALLE = item.DETALLE,
                        TIPOPRODUCTOID = item.TIPOPRODUCTOID,
                        CANTIDAD = item.CANTIDAD,
                        UNIDADMEDIDAID = item.UNIDADMEDIDAID,
                        PRECIOVENTA = item.PRECIOVENTA,
                        PRECIOCOSTO = item.PRECIOCOSTO,
                        PROVEEDORID = item.PROVEEDORID
                    

                    }; 


                    list.Add(newProduct);
                }
               
            }
            foreach (var item in tipoApiFiltered)
            {
                if (tipoApiFiltered !=null)
                {
                    var newTipo = new TIPOPRODUCTO()
                    {
                        ID = item.ID,
                        DESCRIPCION = item.DESCRIPCION

                    };
                    list3.Add(newTipo);

                }

            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: que quieres unir, que listas quieres unir, recuerda que deben ser del mismo tipo de datos

Comment: Quiero unir los objetos declarados en las variables list , list1, list2, list 3 en una nueva variable llamada result, con el objetivo de poder retornar la variable result, y contenga información de todas las tablas intermedias

Comment: Nicolas, y son del mismo tipo?